# MFC Ribbon CEdit Textbox Allignment in Panel

Tags: layout, mfc, controls, ribbon, cedit

I am trying to align two text boxes with two buttons in a panel, and I am unable to find anything about how to force positioning inside the MFC Ribbon Panels.

Here is a picture of what I have currently.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEXN6.jpg  (Sorry wont let me post images yet, have to link.)

The Change View Date box has the box associated with it sitting below it and the change system date box is up in the top right in the second "column" of controls. I would like to fix this so the Box with the spin controls sits next to the CHange View Date and the box without the controls sits next to Change System Date.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think yow cannot do it.
What you can do is to put a Ribbon Separator after the Box with the spin controls and then set the property 'Center Column Vertically' on the Panel.

Hope it can help.